# Using post request in curl

Tags: php, curl

I wrote some lines in php for a post request.
Trying on firefox the request works but not with curl.

```
  public function action($key, $file){
       $this->ch = curl_init();
       $headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
       $headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
       $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

       $datas = "arg=test&action=upload";
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test.com");
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->agent);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_path);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_path);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datas);
       curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);

       $result = json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch));
       echo curl_error($this->ch);
       $info = curl_getinfo($this->ch);
       var_dump($info);
       curl_close($this->ch);
       var_dump($result);
 }
```

So I have no error but the header of the out is the following :
GET / HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax), Mozilla Host: test.com Accept: */* Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Why does the header is using GET and no POST ?
Could you please help me.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand all of the question, but I can show you what the cURL request and response might look like.  A POST-method request does not care about the user-agent.  See if this makes sense to you.  I just sent the information to my request reflector.  You can see it in action here:
https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_f42.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_f42.php
/**
 * Working with cURL
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267667/using-post-request-in-curl#45267667
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


// FROM THE POST AT STACK
function action($key, $file){
    $this_agent = NULL; // NOT IMPORTANT WITH POST REQUEST
    $this_cookie_path = 'cookie.txt';

       $this_ch = curl_init();
       $headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
       $headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
       $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

       $datas = "arg=test&action=upload";
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://iconoun.com/demo/request_reflector.php");
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this_agent);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this_cookie_path);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this_cookie_path);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datas);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);

       $result = curl_exec($this_ch);
       echo curl_error($this_ch);
       $info = curl_getinfo($this_ch);
       var_dump($info);
       curl_close($this_ch);
       var_dump($result);
 }

 action(NULL, NULL);
```

The response looks something like this...

```html
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(46) "https://iconoun.com/demo/request_reflector.php"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(271)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(215)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.166215)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.05617)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.056595)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.098641)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(22)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(231)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(1389)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(132)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(22)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.159707)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(12) "69.65.21.212"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(443)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(12) "69.65.21.212"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(58922)
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(193) "POST /demo/request_reflector.php HTTP/1.1
Host: iconoun.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 22

"
}
string(231) "REQUEST REFLECTED FROM (empty referrer) AT 2017-07-23T12:09:31-05:00
$_COOKIE: array(0) {
}

$_GET: array(0) {
}

$_POST: array(2) {
  ["arg"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["action"]=>
  string(6) "upload"
}

$_FILES: array(0) {
}

"
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time. So I try to reproduce the same code with your url and with mine.
Yours return a POST header mine a GET Header !
The only difference was about the httpS. So I switch to https and now I also send a POST header.
If you have the explanation I would be happy to hear but thanks to you it's working

Comment: I don't know - there may be other factors in play.  In the absence of an affirmative POST request, cURL will make a GET request.  Maybe there is a redirect involved?  But that should not change the request type.